# Implementing a targeted service using XMPP

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I'm using XMPP to drive a notification system. Basically I will have a set of services, some of which will broadcast to all users and some which are directed to a specific client (full JID).

For a service that broadcasts to all users a PubSub node seems the obvious choice but for a service that targets its messages to a specific client, I'm unsure of the best mechanism to use.

Do I represent these services as other client users and create bespoke implementations for them? The problem I see with this is how will they be discovered? Do I group them into a chat room and discover that. It feels like a bit of a hack. I could also define my own bespoke type of service, but then I have to define my own XML tags and maintain that.

I know there are plenty of standard extensions to XMPP but I cant see anything useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the pubsub case, the publisher (i.e. your service) is still a "user", so this configuration will be pretty standard.  We simply create service accounts to represent those "users".

I am unsure of what you mean by "how will they be discovered".  Why do the services need to be discovered?  Your scenario only gives the use case of services sending messages to the users.  Assuming the service already knows who the message is to be sent to, then you don't need any other information to send a message.